# How to replace levels with certain value?

Tags: r

I have a categorical variable in my dataset. I want to replace the levels which are present in test dataset and not present in training set with a value called "others"

Here is how it looks:

`levels(training$var1)` has levels as "1"  "2"  "3"  "Others"

`levels(testing$var1)` has levels as "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

I want to replace all the levels in testing data which are not training data. To achieve this I take the difference between the levels first.

```
a <- setdiff(levels(levels(testing$var1),training$var1)).
```

and I get output as

`levels(a)` as "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

Now I need to replace all the above difference values with "Others". Kindly note that I do not want to drop out these levels but I want to replace with "Others".

For this I tried

```
testing$var1[testing$var1 == "4" <- 'Others"  
testing$var1[testing$var1 == "5" <- 'Others" ==> these works.
```

However I want to make it in run time, something like this:

```
testing$var1[testing$var1 == a[1,] <- 'Others"
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be able to achieve this with the following code:

```
testing$var1 <- as.character(testing$var1)
a <- data.frame(a)
testing$var1 [testing$var1 %in% a[1,] <- "Others"
testing$var1 <- as.factor(testing$var1)
```

In case if there is any other better/effective solution/function to achieve this, please let me know.

Thanks all.